# Change object variables without changing previous instances?

Tags: java, list, object

I'm writing a deck of cards program and I'm experimenting with a `card` object that holds 3 variables: `rank`, `value`, and `suit`.

I made a card object and gave it the value of a 3 of Hearts. (`suit = Hearts, Rank = Three, value = 3`). and add it to a list called `cards`.

I then **change the values of the previous card object** to a 4 of Hearts. (`suit = Hearts, Rank = Four, value = 4`), and add that to the `cards` list.

However, when I print the values of `deck[0],`(3 of Hearts) and `deck[1]` (4 of Hearts), my output is :
`[Hearts, Four, 4]
[Hearts, Four, 4]`

I understand why it's happening, I'm changing the object I put inside the list, and the values are updating accordingly.

Is there a way that I could somehow "disconnect" the object I've placed inside the list from the object I'm changing? I ***seriously*** don't want to make 52 objects for all the cards.

My Code :

***Card Object :***

```java
class Card
{
    private static String suit;
    private static String rank;
    private static int value;

    public Card() {

    }

    public Card(String s, String r, int v) {
        suit = s;
        rank = r;
        value = v;
    }

    public static void setValues(String s, String r, int v) {
        suit = s;
        rank = r;
        value = v;
    }

    public static void toString(Card card) {
        System.out.println("[" + card.suit + ", " + card.rank + ", " + card.value + "]");
    }

}
```

***Main Code :***

```java
    public void test() {
        Card card = new Card("Hearts", "Three", 3); //Making 3 of Hearts
        cards[0] = card;                            //Assigning to slot 0 in cards

        Card.setValues("Hearts", "Four", 4);        //Changing values to 4 of Hearts
        cards[1]= card;                             //Assigning to slot 1 in cards

        Card.toString(cards[0]);                    
        Card.toString(cards[1]);
    }
}
```

quick edit : Changing "Card.setValues" to "card.setValues" didn't do much, but I thought i'd let yall know

Comment: Yes, you need to create 52 objects.  That is what collections are for.

Comment: When you put something into an array, it's not a copy - it's "the actual thing". So in your code you have the same object at `[0]` and at `[1]`.

Comment: Perhaps you could make your card objects immutable. That way you can't change the value of one in a list.

Comment: In your Card class, make the class variables not static.  In your test method, change the call from the setValues method to card = new Card("Hearts", "Four", 4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missunderstood some basic concepts here.

If you declare an attribute as [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) it becomes a class attribute, which means it is accesssable for all objects of the type card and always holds the same value for these objects.
Instead if you remove the static modifier the value is unique for every instance of the object.
The same concept applies to static methods.

If you reuse the same instance of a card (like you intend to do) you will always change the value of all cards in the array, because basically you just added the same card multiple times and then changed its value. This happens because by assigning `cards[1]= card;` you create a link to the card object and not a copy of it.

Due to this there is no way around creating a object for each card.

You should probably watch some tutorials about OOP (object oriented programming) in Java.